# Want "Menu" example--Pico demo fails

Tags: menu, rascal

In looking for a working example of "Menu" for the DSL I am writing, I tried "Pico". But the following fails:

```
rascal>import demo::lang::Pico::Plugin;
|plugin://rascal_eclipse/src/org/rascalmpl/eclipse/library/demo/lang/Pico/Plugin.rsc|(1791,48,<71,6>,<71,54>): The called signature: action(str, void (...)),
does not match any of the declared (overloaded) signature patterns:
Menu = action(str,void (Tree, loc))
Menu = action(str,void (str, loc))
```

If I comment out lines 71-73 of "Plugin.rsc" it loads successfully, but then of course I have no "Menu". Can someone point me to a fix of this (which doesn't require much Eclipse or Java expertise :) or to a different working example of "Menu"?

Thanks

My environment:

> Rascal:     (I don't know how to print the version, but one of the
>   files is
>                   rascal_eclipse_0.7.3.201506091957.jar )
>
> Eclipse:    for RCP and RAP Developers Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
>   Java:       version "1.8.0_51" OS:         Linux Mint 17 Qiana

Answer (score 1):

Popup menus can be added as contributions to your registered language using 
the `popup(Menu menu)` constructor. After you have created the contributions that you need call the `registerContribution(..)` (defined in `util::IDE`) function supplying the constructed `Contribution` data type.

For example, in Pico the contributions are defined as follows:

```
public set[Contribution] Pico_CONTRIBS = {
  popup(
    menu("Pico",[
        action("Evaluate Pico program", evalPicoProgram),
        action("Compile Pico to ASM", compilePicoProgram),
        action("Show Control flow graph", visualizePicoProgram)
    ])
  )
};
```

The signature of the `evalPicoProgram`, `compilePicoProgram` and `visualizePicoProgram` are

```
public void _name_(Tree x, loc selection) {
  ...
}
```

Eventually the contributions get registered with the following code:

```
registerContributions("Pico", Pico_CONTRIBS);
```

---

In the Pico example the menu that was registered contained an `action` constructors with a wrong type. This was indeed a bug in Rascal. The signature of the action constructor changed in the past and the Pico Plugin module was not updated accordingly.

I made the necessary changes and it should be fixed in the newest unstable version of Rascal.

Comment: maybe you could copy in the Pico code here, just for completeness sake